# Setting a maximim inactive interval for cookies?

Tags: jsp, cookies

IS there any way to set the maximumtime a cookie can be inactive in java? I am asking this because for the cookie class(in java docs) there is no method called setmaxinactiveinterval().

Comment: @Jigar Joshi : No Joshi saab, please read the question more carefully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cookie class has a method [setMaxAge](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/javax/servlet/http/Cookie.html#setMaxAge%28int%29), I hope that can be useful for you.

```
public void setMaxAge(int expiry)
```

If that doesn't work for you, You can store current time with cookie value and when you fetch it, just read and compare the stored time value and the time of reading the cookie, if the difference is more than the desired value. You can discard the cookie and treat it as an expired cookie.

However I strongly recommend using the Cookies's setMaxAge() or similar method of Session class,